# How can I put an image in my email markdown header?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.8

I am trying to replace the app name in a Laravel markdown email header with an image but I am not having a lot of success.

message.blade.php

```
@component('mail::layout')
{{-- Header --}}
@slot('header')
    @component('mail::header', ['url' => config('app.url')])
        @if(config('app.site.logo'))
            <img src="{{ url(config('app.site.logo')) }}" class="site- 
logo" height="50" />
        @else
            {{ config('app.site.name', 'Campaign') }}
        @endif
    @endcomponent
@endslot

{{-- Body --}}
{{ $slot }}

{{-- Subcopy --}}
@isset($subcopy)
    @slot('subcopy')
        @component('mail::subcopy')
            {{ $subcopy }}
        @endcomponent
    @endslot
@endisset

{{-- Footer --}}
@slot('footer')
    @component('mail::footer')
        &copy; {{ date('Y') }} {{ config('app.site.name', 'Campaign') }}. 
@lang('All rights reserved.')
    @endcomponent
@endslot
@endcomponent
```

followup.blade.php <-- email markdown page

```
@component('mail::message')
 ## Follow up reminder

Set for today {{ date('l \t\h\e jS \of F Y', strtotime($member->FollowUp)) }} with  {{$member->LastName}} {{$member->FirstName}} / {{$member->Position}}

@component('mail::panel', ['url' => ''])
@if(count($member->notes))

*notes...*
@foreach($member->notes->sortByDesc("created_at") as $note)

**{!! nl2br(e($note->note)) !!}** 

by *{{$note->user->name}}.*

@endforeach

@else
 No notes added for member
@endif
@endcomponent
Probable Vote: {{$member->LikelyVote}}
@component('mail::button', ['url' => $the_url])
View Information
@endcomponent


 Thank you,
{{ config('app.site.name', 'Campaign application A.I.') }}
@endcomponent
```

Everything works on mailtrap and the header image shows up. The image does not show up in gmail.

Comment: You edited the question to be a totally different question, invalidating my answer.  If a question is substantially different from the original you ask, then ask it as a seperate question.

Comment: Sorry about that, second time using stack overflow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Original Question - How to get rid of "Laravel" in the header

#### Set the App Name

In your .env set the

```
APP_NAME="YOUR APPLICATIONS NAME"
```

Which is where the Laravel in the header is coming from.

#### Or Modify the Template

You can have more control by publishing the source for the [markdown mailables](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/mail) by running:

```
php artisan vendor:publish --tag=laravel-mail
```

And editing them at `resources/views/vendor/mail`

### Images

The way to include images from your server is:

```
   ![Some option text][logo]

   [logo]: {{asset('/img/official_logo.png')}} "Logo"
```

Otherwise, you can get the base64 encoding and drop that into an img tag to truely embed the image (after reading it into a variable (image)):

```
<img src="data:image/jpg;base64,{{ base64_encode($image) }}">
```

Comment: Thanks your first response for the original question of How to get rid of "Laravel" in the header. It worked great. The second part I am working on. the code did not work after being placed in the message.blade.php file. Voting correct because the answer to the original question was correct.

Comment: I tried the first option and it did not work. The text just showed up in my email instead of the image. It works on mailtrap but not gmail. I have tried several gmail accounts. I have other mail that has images in them. I am working on the second option and trying to figure out how to read the image into a variable. I will let you know how it works out. thanks,

Comment: I'm using the markdown version currently.  Yes, gmail won't display the images without the user clicking "display images" if the image is on a server and not part of the email.

Comment: I used this image from stackoverflow and it works fine... <img src="https://avatars2.githubusercontent.com/u/36575297?s=180&v=4" alt="Logo" title="Logo" style="display:block" width="50" height="50" />   it is just when I try to use any of the images in my public file they do not work. I just see a blank image icon with a link that takes me to local host. I double checked over and over to make sure I had the right file locations and names of images and the image file type.

Comment: That means the image location you supplied isn't quite right.

Comment: Would it makes since that it works in mailtrap.io if the location isn't right?

Comment: Thanks everything you said worked with an images on a live site and just not from within my local environment.

Comment: Depending on what the address looks like, google may be sanitizing it for security reasons.  Which might explain why they are showing in mailtrap but not in gmail.  The other option is the thing I first mentioned about "dislplay images" in gmail.

Answer (score 0):

This is the best answer to the question of embedding images in Laravel Markdown mailables.

Want to echo what @Elcapeetan said about Mailtrap because it wasn't clear to me at first.

If you are using Mailtrap, running in a local dev environment, and use the first image method the mail will contain the link to your **local** server but Mailtrap can't display that. It will likely work in production though.

If you use the base64 encoding approach, that **does** work in Mailtrap and in production.